# VBA-скрипт на системе с англоязычной локализацией заполняет строки с кириллицей некорректно

Tags: windows, excel, кодировка, vba, перекодировка

Есть VBA-скрипт, который успешно заполнял заголовки таблицы и свойства в Excel на Windows с русской локализацией. При переносе его на англоязычную, пошли проблемы с краказябрами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Public Function FillTable(in_fileName As String)
    Dim wkb As Workbook ' Рабочая книга
    Dim wks As Worksheet ' рабочий лист
    
    Set wkb = Workbooks(in_fileName)
    wkb.Activate
    Set wks = wkb.ActiveSheet
    wks.Activate

    wks.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Номер СЗ"
    wkb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title") = "Ежедневный отчет"
End Function
```

Были попытки с конвертацией строки:

```
wks.Cells(1, 1).Value = StrConv("Номер СЗ", vbUnicode)
wkb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title") = StrConv("Ежедневный отчет", vbUnicode)
```

Но это все равно не помогло.

Работа происходит с Excel2016.